# Is it possible to trace a file's history?

Tags: ubuntu, file-management

A file recently appeared on my desktop, an image of a chess board.

I'd like to know a bit more about it. Unfortunately, thinking it was a gift from someone I knew, I have opened it in Gimp, modified it, and saved it. So I can't even see what day the file was created (since ls -al only shows me date modified, not date created).

Is there some utility for learning more about a file in Ubuntu (the OS I am using)?

Comment: You could try opening it in a hex-editor to see if there is any metadata that gives clues as to its origin, but the program you used to edit it may or may not have retained the original metadata.

Comment: Mystery solved with regards to the file itself: turns out it is exactly what I thought it was! Question still stands.

Comment: Well how did you figure it out? Next time, just use whatever technique you used this time.

Comment: Ha ha, yes: it was an HR problem that I solved in the HR domain. I'd like a more general solution for the future. Good suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your sub-question: To see the date the file was created, add `-U` (OS X and other BSDs) or `-c` (Linux) to your `ls` options.

See also `stat(1)`.

If you were on a Mac and use Time Machine, or if you were using an app that makes use of autosave in OS X 10.7 Lion and later, use Time Machine to check for previous revisions of the file, and then check their metadata using a tool that understands the metadata of that file format.

Depending on what OS you're on, there may be other pieces of metadata (extended attributes, etc.) for the file embedded in the filesystem's entry for that file, not in the file itself. So the answer would vary by OS.

*It's always good to specify which OS(es) and OS versions you're talking about when asking questions here. Gimp runs lots of places including OS X and Windows, so we can't assume you meant a certain flavor of Linux just because you said you used Gimp.*

Comment: Thanks for the note there: I am on linux. It appears that the -c option for ls just displays the last modified time?

Comment: Even the created timestamp may be changed depending on how the program the OP edited it with behaves. It may copy the created timestamp of the original file to the modified file, or it may just leave it with the current time.

Comment: @Ziggy Oops, I didn't read the Linux man page carefully enough. `-c` lists/sorts by the ctime, which is the last time the inode was changed, not its creation time. Filesystems in use with OS X and other BSDs have a real file creation time (birth time). I don't know the details of this on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some utility for learning more about a file in Ubuntu (the OS I am using)?

IF its is installed you can use the **file** command.

It will give you general information about the file.

```
file /folder/subfolder/file.ext
```

If you have clam AV installed

```
clamscan /folder/subfolder/file.ext
```

Will give you an indication if it might be a virus.  False positive and negatives are a thing.

You would have to have certain configurations to have any hope of tracing anything.

If you are using BTRFS file system and your OS is using subvolumes for snapshoting the hard drive you may be able to retrieve earlier version of the file.

Anything else would require some kind of monitoring software to exist in advance.